# CMake based project on WSL2 does not show missing/undefined symbol errors for unimplemented functions

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake, wsl-2

Before we start my environment:

- gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
- cmake version 3.16.3
- Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
- VSCode Version: 1.66.1 with Extensions

  - C/C++v1.9.7
  - C/C++ Extension Pack v1.1.0
  - CMake v0.0.17 by twxs
  - CMake Tools v1.10.5 by Microsoft

I am currently setting up a new CMake based C11 project running in a WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 environment that I want to work with using VSCode.
Due to the amount of possible files, I have uploaded an [example project to my github account](https://github.com/knmiecc/ErrorShyCMakeProject) that shows this error.

The project I have set up is recognised by VSCode and the extensions as a CMake project. It can be configured through VSCode and after the initial config step I get a set of build targets that allow me to compile both library targets and executables that I find in an extra build/ directory within the project. So far so good.

My issue now is that, coming from another Autoconf/Make based project, I was used to VSCode being very, VERY keen to show errors for missing and undefined symbols by itself and without having to manually compile any target.

With my CMake project imagine the following trivial example main as found in the repo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", "C: main() called");
    myUnknownSymbol();
}
```

I would expect the function `myUnknownSymbol` to get a **red squiggle** line, but not only does it now show up prior to compiling the project through VSCode but it also only tells me via a yellow squiggle

```
implicit declaration of function ‘myUnknownSymbol’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] GCC
```

I have tried to compare the project setup, the user, workspace and extension settings for both my projects and I am honestly unable to find any reason why the IntelliSense is not automatically picking this up as an error other than because the CMake provider does not provide such a feature.

I tried experimenting with using different configurations for my c_cpp_properties.json, using e.g. different intelliSenseMode values, but to no avail.

For completion's sake the project's c_cpp_properties.json file inside the .vscode/ dir:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++11",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestion whether this can be set up at all?